# Build Type which implements generic type parameter interfaces through Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following structure:

```
namespace A
{
  abstract public class BaseClass<To, T> { }
}

namespace A.B
{
  interface IFooB { double Prop1 { get; set; } }

  abstract public class BaseSubClassB<T> : A.BaseClass<float, T> { }

  public class SubClassB<T> : BaseSubClassB<T> where T : IFooB { }
}

namespace A.C
{
  interface IFooC { double Prop2 { get; set; } }

  abstract public class BaseSubClassC<T> : A.BaseClass<bool, T> { }

  pubic class SubClassC<T> : BaseSubClassC<T> where T : IFooC { }
}
```

I also have a method that recursively gives the list of non-abstract generic and non-generic Types that inherit from a base type in the same assembly like so

```
public static List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(Type baseType) { ... };
```

such that `GetAllDerivedTypes(typeof(A.BaseClass<, >))` basically returns

```
List<Type> allSubClasses = new List<Type> {typeof(A.B.SubclassB<>), typeof(A.C.SubClassC<>)}
```

Now I would like to create an instance of each of these collected Types in `allSubClasses`. The goal here is to check in unit tests if calling some methods defined in the base class on each instance does not throw any exceptions.
How I understand it, I would have to do something like the following:

```
foreach(var type in allSubClasses)
{
  Type constructedType = type.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(TYPEPARAMETER) });
  var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);
  Assert.That(obj.operation()); <- OK
}
```

where `TYPEPARAMETER` could be a class which provides all the Properties needed in the type parameters of the subclasses in `allSubClasses`, e.g.

```
public class TYPEPARAMETER : A.B.IFooB, A.C.IFooC, ...
{
  double Prop1 { get; set; }
  double Prop2 { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Would that be a valid approach to create the instances?
And if yes, what would be a way to build `TYPEPARAMETER` at runtime through Reflection which implements all required interfaces and their properties?

---

**EDIT:**

I looked at `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder` to build `TYPEPARAMETER` through Reflection. How do I get all generic type parameter interfaces `A.B.IFooB, A.C.IFooC, ...` of the collected subclasses `allSubClasses` in order to build `TYPEPARAMETER` as described?

Comment: Whether it would be a valid approach depends on what you want to achieve with these instances. I suggest expanding your question a little in this direction. As for creating such a type with reflection, it is certainly possible: if you want to do this at runtime, look at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: Thank you! I extended and edited the text by providing more information for what I try to do with the instances and specifying my question.

Comment: You can get the type parameter interfaces by calling `Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints` on each of `allSubClasses`' type parameter, i.e. `subClass.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericParameterConstraints()[0]` should yield the interface. Note that `type.GetGenericArguments()` returns generic type _parameters_ if `type` is a generic type definition (`Class<>`).

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: Thank you, I was able to implement what I needed. However, instead of `Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints()` I ended up using `Type.GetInterfaces()` because `GetGenericParameterConstraints()` was only returning all direct type constraints and not other existing hierarchical/recursive interface constraints.

Comment: I went by your example code, where GGPC() should have been sufficient. GGPC() and other such methods do return basically what is in the corresponding metadata table, heavy lifting such as walking up hiearchies almost always has to be done manually.